# Sql query to map user log table to user first, last and previous activity

Tags: mysql, sql, etl

I have a user log table, partitioned on action_date (table name - user_action_log) consisting billions of rows, with columns

> user_id, action_name, action_date

Sample data -

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| user_id | action_name | action_date |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 123     | login       | 2018-01-30  |
| 123     | logout      | 2018-01-31  |
| 123     | click       | 2018-02-28  |
| 123     | comment     | 2018-02-15  |
| 123     | post        | 2018-03-15  |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

I want to write an ETL/sql to transform this data into something like this (table name - user_action_record).

> user_id (Primary key), first_action_date, last_action_date, previous_action_date

Sample output data -

```
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------------+
| user_id | first_action_date | last_action_date | previous_last_action_date |
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------------+
| 123     | 2018-01-30        | 2018-03-15       | 2018-02-28                |
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------------+
```

I tried dividing problem into 2 steps -

1. Insert new users which are not present in user_action_record.
2. Update existing user by updating "previous_last_action_date" from value in "last_action_date" and update last_action_date based on user_action_log table.

The problem is that, since user_action_log is partitioned on action_date, i can query that table on a daily basis (action_date = CURRENT_DATE)

Can anybody help me with sqls to populate my target table in this case?

-- Edited with additional info below

1. Source and expected target table on day '2018-01-30'

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| user_id | action_name | action_date |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 123     | login       | 2018-01-30  |
| 123     | logout      | 2018-01-30  |
| 123     | click       | 2018-01-30  |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

```
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------------+
| user_id | first_action_date | last_action_date | previous_last_action_date |
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------------+
| 123     | 2018-01-30        | 2018-01-30       | 2018-01-30                |
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------------+
```

2. Source and expected target table on day '2018-01-31'

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| user_id | action_name | action_date |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 123     | login       | 2018-01-30  |
| 123     | logout      | 2018-01-30  |
| 123     | click       | 2018-01-30  |
| 123     | login       | 2018-01-31  |
| 123     | logout      | 2018-01-31  |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

```
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------------+
| user_id | first_action_date | last_action_date | previous_last_action_date |
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------------+
| 123     | 2018-01-30        | 2018-01-31       | 2018-01-30                |
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------------+
```

3. Source and expected target table on day '2018-02-15'

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| user_id | action_name | action_date |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 123     | login       | 2018-01-30  |
| 123     | logout      | 2018-01-30  |
| 123     | click       | 2018-01-30  |
| 123     | login       | 2018-01-31  |
| 123     | logout      | 2018-01-31  |
| 123     | logout      | 2018-02-15  |
| 123     | logout      | 2018-02-15  |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

```
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------------+
| user_id | first_action_date | last_action_date | previous_last_action_date |
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------------+
| 123     | 2018-01-30        | 2018-02-15       | 2018-01-31                |
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff 5.6

Comment: Would be a lot easier in MySQL 8, with `DENSE_RANK()`

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a ranking function in MySQL < 8 with a self-join on `user_id` where the row in the second table has a later `action_date`:

```
SELECT u1.*, COUNT(u2.user_id) AS rn
FROM user_action_log u1
LEFT JOIN user_action_log u2 ON u2.user_id = u1.user_id AND u2.action_date > u1.action_date
GROUP BY u1.user_id, u1.action_name, u1.action_date
ORDER BY rn;
```

Output:

```
user_id action_name action_date rn
123     post        2018-03-15  0
123     click       2018-02-28  1
123     comment     2018-02-15  2
123     logout      2018-01-31  3
123     login       2018-01-30  4
```

This table can then be used as a derived table, and we can find the `previous_last_action_date` from the row with `rn = 1`:

```
SELECT user_id,
       MIN(action_date) AS first_action_date,
       MAX(action_date) AS last_action_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN action_date END) AS previous_last_action_date
FROM (SELECT u1.*, COUNT(u2.user_id) AS rn
      FROM user_action_log u1
      LEFT JOIN user_action_log u2 ON u2.user_id = u1.user_id AND u2.action_date > u1.action_date
      GROUP BY u1.user_id, u1.action_name, u1.action_date) ual
GROUP BY user_id
```

Output:

```
user_id first_action_date   last_action_date    previous_last_action_date
123     2018-01-30          2018-03-15          2018-02-28
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qNmSyU25JvCQrUvxtZgpyW/2)

Comment: this query will work but as mentioned in the question source table has billions of rows and partitioned on action_date. So any query spanning multiple partitions would fail. Hence, this query wont work in this scenario. On top of that records will be added daily to source table, so i need a way to update/insert users daily. recreating the target table from scratch is not an option.

Comment: Added more data in the question

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of MySQL, you can use the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick:

```
select user_id,
       min(action_date) as first_action_date,
       max(action_date) as last_action_date,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(action_date order by action_date desc), ',', 2), ',', -1) as second_to_last_date
from user_action_log ual
group by user_id;
```

Another alternative is a correlated subqueries:

```
select user_id,
       min(action_date) as first_action_date,
       max(action_date) as last_action_date,
       (select max(ual2.action_date)
        from user_action_log ual2
        where ual2.user_id = ual.user_id and
              ual2.action_date < max(ual.action_date)
      ) as second_to_last_date
from user_action_log ual
group by user_id;
```

Comment: this query will work but as mentioned in the question source table has billions of rows and partitioned on action_date. So any query spanning multiple partitions would fail. Hence, this query wont work in this scenario. On top of that records will be added daily to source table, so i need a way to update/insert users daily. recreating the target table from scratch is not an option.

Comment: Added more data in the question